# Very simple Keras binary classification doesn't work

Tags: python, keras

Can someone please explain why the following code achieves only about 50% classification accuracy?

I am trying to classify lists of 20 items into 0 or 1. The lists are all 5s or all 6s.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

positive_samples = [[5]*20]*100
negative_samples = [[6]*20]*100

x_list = np.array(positive_samples+negative_samples, dtype=np.float32)
y_list = np.array([1]*len(positive_samples)+[0]*len(negative_samples), dtype=np.float32)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_list, y_list, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 2)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 2)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=20, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
print (model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the last output layer has `2` values per sample, you need to use a `softmax` activation instead of `sigmoid`.

Also, that means `binary_crossentropy` cannot be used, and you have to use `categorical_crossentropy`.

I have also normalized the dataset `x_list` by dividing with the maximum (`6`).

```
x_list /= x_list.max()
```

Also, you need to shuffle the dataset, by passing `shuffle=True` in `train_test_split`.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

positive_samples = [[5]*20]*100
negative_samples = [[6]*20]*100

x_list = np.array(positive_samples+negative_samples, dtype=np.float32)
y_list = np.array([1]*len(positive_samples)+[0]*len(negative_samples), dtype=np.float32)

x_list /= x_list.max()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_list, y_list, test_size=0.20, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 2)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 2)

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
print (model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0))
```

A sigmoid activation in the output makes sense only when there is `1` output, in which the value would be in range `[0, 1]` signifying probability of the instance being a `1`.

In case of `2` (or more) output neurons, it is necessary we normalize the probabilities to sum upto 1 so we use a `softmax` layer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Data should be normalized before feeding it to the network, this is normally done by changing the values to be between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. Setting the input to;

```
positive_samples = [[1]*20]*100
negative_samples = [[-1]*20]*100
```

works or the model could be changed to:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
```